# OTG Support on latest Nexus flagships 5X, 6P

Tags: usb-on-the-go, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-6p, nexus-5x

The recent flagships featuring USB Type-C connections have no mention of on-the-go USB flash accessory support. Does anybody know whether it's there, has anyone tried it?
What are the necessary cables for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Google search on XDA forums shows both phones support  OTG

Nexus 6P. [USB OTG](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/help/usb-otg-t3238449). Shows connectors and retailer info

Nexus 5X [Nexus 5X OTG support from Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/qWgDNtBtlrg)

[USB standards](http://www.usb.org/developers/usbtypec/) from USB.org  also has pictures of three types of connectors and general info

Comment: Nexus 5X is something different than Nexus 5.

Comment: @MaxRied thanks for pointing out my error. Edited the answer